# How to add to the number value of an object property in Javascript / Angular5

Tags: javascript, json, object, angular5

I am building an app that records my spending with Angular 5. I want to take the data input which includes an integer(spend amount) and a date and basically show a daily spend amount as well as total spend and other weekly categories etc. The first thing I have been trying to get is a daily spend. So I thought it would be best to add dynamically to an object containing with property as date and value as total spend amount for that day. Adding dynamically to the object if the date in question doesn't exist yet. The part which currently doesn't work is that I can't seem to add to the value of an already defined property (e.g a date)

```
  dailySpends = 
 {
  "2017-12-01": 0, // <-- I want to add to this with every new entry that is also on this date for a running total.

 }
```

I have a function which works on click called addItem(), it does a number of things and one of the things I want it to do is add to this running daily total. So far I have written this.

```
  for(var key in this.dailySpends){
    if(this.dailySpends[key] == this.date){
      this.dailySpends[key]  +=   this.spendAmount; //<<--Problematic line
      alert(Object.entries(this.dailySpends)); //alert for checking entry
    }
    else this.dailySpends[this.date] = this.spendAmount;
    alert(Object.entries(this.dailySpends)) //alert for checking entry
  }
```

So update the object fine when new dates are put in, but I cant seem to update the value of already defined properties. Would it be better if I was working with an array, or is there a simple way of adding to it that I am missing.

Comment: On second line you're checking this.dailySpends[key] (value) against the date which is the key. Shouldn't it be key == this.date?

Comment: Also this.date might be of type Date and you might need to convert it to the format of your key before comparing.